Macro copy, add/remove last token
Suppose I have a macro with only argument that has such a structure
\def\foo#1{%
  {\textbf{#1}}{aaa}{bbb}
}

I need to create two copies:

\bar that is \foo but withouot the last token: \copyremovelast{\foo}{\bar} ⮧
 \def\bar#1{%
   {\textbf{#1}}{aaa}
 }


\baz that is \foo but plus an additional token that might contain #1: \copyaddlast{\foo}{\bar}{\textit{#1}} ⮧
 \def\baz#1{%
   {\textbf{#1}}{aaa}{bbb}{\textit{#1}}
 }



I'm looking for both plain tex and latex3 solutions. The shortest the solution the better.

Note that I want to avoid using etoolbox that allows to make the latter pretty easy
\let\baz\foo
\apptocmd{\baz}{\textit{#1}}{}{}

but \apptocmd is overkill if you look how it's implemented. My goal is to achieve that manually with least lines of code.

note the last token in the replacement text of \foo is the space token after {bbb} so interpreting removing the last token as removing {bbb} implies stripping space first (which makes the code considerably more complicated) is that intended? or did you intend to have a % in the definition to avoid adding a space there?

there is no short solution for the first, you could detokenize it use an l3regex to remove the last brace group, then rescan assuming standard catcodes and hope to get the right thing. Doing it with "plain tex" isn't really feasible unless you know the "last brace group" is the third brace group as removing everything after the first two is easy enough.

When you say it 'has such a structure' what, exactly, is known about it? Is the last (but one) token always followed by a space?

For an expl3 solution, the recent question Convert control sequence with a variable number of undelimited parameters into a token list gets you pretty close. But if you think that etoolbox uses too much code for its internals, then anything in expl3 is going to seem insanely excessive.

@MaxChernoff If nothing else, the name of every macro must be 10 times longer.

There is no space at the end, my bad. I formatted it for readability. By structure I mean that it's always N consequent groups {...}{...}{...}...{...}.

@DavidCarlisle for \baz I tried \tl_put_right:Nn and it almost worked. The only problem is that the first token I put right gets interpreted as an argument and all #1 are replaced with it. But the following \tl_put_right:Nn result in the expected way.

you could fix the # handling for adding to the end but removing almost certainly requires more code than is justified. I do suspect this is an x-y question what it the actual use case, perhaps if you stored the structure in something designed to be added/replaced such as a _seq then things would be easier.

It seems unlikley that this is a good way of doing whatever the real use case is, but I think this does what is requested so long (for removal) there are at most 8 groups in the original definition.
It produces terminal output:
> \foo=macro:
#1->{\textbf {#1}}{aaa}{bbb}.
l.7 \show\foo
             
? 
> \baz=macro:
#1->{\textbf {#1}}{aaa}{bbb}{\textit {#1}}.
l.14 \show\baz
              
? 
> \bar=macro:
#1-> {\textbf {#1}}{aaa}.
l.32 \show\bar
              
? 

from
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{%
  {\textbf{#1}}{aaa}{bbb}%
}

\show\foo

\def\copyaddlast#1#2#3{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter##\expandafter1\expandafter{#1{##1}{#3}}}


\copyaddlast{\foo}{\baz}{\textit{#1}}
\show\baz

\def\copyremovelast#1#2{%
  \expandafter\edef\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\copyremovelastx#1{##1}!!!!!!!!!\relax}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter##\expandafter1\expandafter{\tmp}}

\def\copyremovelastx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9\relax{
    \ifx!#2\else{\unexpanded{#1}}\fi
    \ifx!#3\else{\unexpanded{#2}}\fi
    \ifx!#4\else{\unexpanded{#3}}\fi
    \ifx!#5\else{\unexpanded{#4}}\fi
    \ifx!#6\else{\unexpanded{#5}}\fi
    \ifx!#7\else{\unexpanded{#6}}\fi
    \ifx!#8\else{\unexpanded{#7}}\fi 
  }
  
\copyremovelast{\foo}{\bar}
\show\bar

\begin{document}

\end{document}

I used ! here as the guard token but it can be any token that does not appear in the original definition groups.

What a concise solution! \copyaddlast is made really neat and smart, \expandafter## is thing I didn't know about. The removal is rather hacky, but it's ok for me, because I wanted to learn how to do when a macro contains #1 it in the first place. In the real use case I always have 6 groups, so I can simply gobble once.

I believe you're using “token” in a different sense than the standard for TeX and you want to remove the last braced group.
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo#1{%
  {\textbf{#1}}{aaa}{bbb}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \cs_parameter_spec:N \foo }
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpb_tl { \cs_replacement_spec:N \foo }

\tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_tmpa_tl { } \l_tmpa_tl
\tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_tmpb_tl { } \l_tmpb_tl
\tl_set:Ne \l_tmpc_tl { \tl_range:Nnn \l_tmpb_tl { 1 } { -2 } }

\use:e {
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \exp_not:N \baz \l_tmpa_tl  { \exp_not:V \l_tmpc_tl }
}
\use:e {
  \cs_set_nopar:Npn \exp_not:N \baz \l_tmpa_tl  { \exp_not:V \l_tmpb_tl \exp_not:N \textit{#1}}
}

\cs_show:N \foo
\cs_show:N \bar
\cs_show:N \baz

\stop

Of course, standard category code are assumed.
> \foo=macro:#1->{\textbf {#1}}{aaa}{bbb}.

> \bar=macro:#1->{\textbf {#1}}{aaa}.

> \baz=macro:#1->{\textbf {#1}}{aaa}{bbb}\textit {#1}.


A really compact latex3 solution. But \cs_replacement_spec:N uses \meaning under the hood which is essentially etoolbox does. I'm curious if It's possible to simplify David Carlisle's solution for adding the last group with latex3. I was trying to do something like \exp_args:NNNo \def\bar#1{\foo{#1} \exp_not:N {test}} with no luck.

@antshar It depends on whether you know the parameter text.

Yes, I see that your solution covers the most general case even if a macro has some weird arguments. But for my particular case it's known that \foo has only one argument, so I'd like to take it into account and get the simplest solution.
